# Bootstrap html use main page for every view

Tags: html, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to create a responsive div container and include it in every html page.
I'm using spring and angular.js and my html page is a jsp.

How can I implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: dynamically or hardcoded?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap recently and I don't know is better for me, I have to do a web app responsive to mobile and desktop. What is your advice?

Comment: Since you are already using Angular - I would make use of Angular's partials and templating. No need to bring in another library if you are comfortable with using Angular.

ie. ngInclude

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Answer (score 1):

You can use some template framework such as Tiles or Thymeleaf. There are plenty of tutorials on how to use them and their documentations are very detailed.
Side note: Thymeleaf is also very well supported by Spring/Spring boot. I would highly recommend that.